# How can I add a marker to Open Layers map?

Tags: javascript, angular, web, openlayers-6

Currently building a map app. Trying all the methods I find in the internet to add a marker, still doesn't work. Am I doing it wrong?

Here's my Angular code:

Somehow, it's much easier with Leaflet, but I don't want to abandon Open Layers that early.

```
export class MapComponent implements OnInit{
  
  map! : Map;
  marker! :any;
  center = fromLonLat([5.5697, 50.6330]);
  iconFeature = new Feature({
    geometry : new Point(fromLonLat([5.5697, 50.6330]))
  })
  
  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.map = new Map({
      view : new View({
        center : this.center,
        zoom : 0
      }),
      layers : [

         new LayerVector({
          source : new SourceVector({
            features : [this.iconFeature]
          }),
          style : new Style({
            image : new Icon({
              anchor : [0.5, 46],
              src : '../assets/istockphoto-1153114937-2048x2048-removebg-preview.png'
            })
          })
         })
         new TileLayer({
       source : new OSM()
         })
      ],
      target :  "map"
    })   
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can u try this example of code

```
import { Map, View } from 'ol';
import { Tile as TileLayer, Vector as LayerVector } from 'ol/layer';
import { OSM, Vector as SourceVector } from 'ol/source';
import Feature from 'ol/Feature';
import Point from 'ol/geom/Point';
import { fromLonLat } from 'ol/proj';
import { Icon, Style } from 'ol/style';

export class MapComponent implements OnInit{
  
  map!: Map;
  center = fromLonLat([5.5697, 50.6330]);

  ngOnInit(): void {

    const marker = new Feature({
      geometry: new Point(fromLonLat([5.5697, 50.6330]))
    });

    const markerLayer = new LayerVector({
      source: new SourceVector({
        features: [marker]
      }),
      style: new Style({
        image: new Icon({
          anchor: [0.5, 1],
          src: '../assets/istockphoto-1153114937-2048x2048-removebg-preview.png'
        })
      })
    });

    this.map = new Map({
      view: new View({
        center: this.center,
        zoom: 0
      }),
      layers: [
        new TileLayer({
          source: new OSM()
        }),
        markerLayer
      ],
      target: 'map'
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Weirdly it works. Why does it matter if I initialize a LayerVector in OnInit?

Comment: @Emma Gorington Layer order is important here - if you add the OSM after the marker layer the marker will be hidden under the OSM.